# How to create a replacement or a decorator of \verb?

Tags: verbatim

I want to create a new macro, which would work exactly like `\verb`, but with my own formatting (colors, rounding box, etc). What is the best way to do this? I'm expecting to use it like this:

```
Hello, |my_name|!
```

Here, I want `my_name` to be printed, say, in red.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have plenty of decorations with `tcolorbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\newcommand{\verbA}{\tcboxverb}
\newcommand{\verbB}{\tcboxverb[colback=blue!10!white,colupper=blue]}
\newcommand{\verbC}{\tcboxverb[blank,fuzzy halo]}
\newcommand{\verbD}{\tcboxverb[beamer]}
\newcommand{\verbE}{\tcboxverb[enhanced,skin=enhancedmiddle jigsaw,colframe=red]}

\catcode`|=\active
\def|{\currentverb|}

\newcommand{\chooseverb}[1]{\let\currentverb#1}
\chooseverb{\verbA} % initialize

\begin{document}

|my_name #{|

\bigskip

\chooseverb{\verbB}

|my_name #{|

\bigskip

\chooseverb{\verbC}

|my_name #{|

\bigskip

\chooseverb{\verbD}

|my_name #{|

\bigskip

\chooseverb{\verbE}

|my_name #{|

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{shortvrb,color}

\MakeShortVerb\|

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\verbatim@font{\color{red}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Hello, |my_name|!
\end{document}
```