# How to get rid of a spaces after tokens in \detokenize?

Tags: detokenize

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\catcode`|=\active
\def|#1|{\texttt{\detokenize{#1}}}
\begin{document}
Hello, |\a\b|!
\end{document}
```

It renders as such:

[image]

The spaces after tokens are a mistake. What's wrong with my code?

BTW, the usage of `\texttt` is just for the sake of experiment. In my real case, I have a more complex macro that expects an argument.

Comment: They are not a mistake: the idea is that if you had output `\ab` in say a `.aux` file, it could be read back as `\ab` but without the space could have been generated from input of `\a` followed by `b`, tokenized separately. We'll need more context to help: one can arrange to apply `\string`, or read verbatim, ..., but it depends on what you want to do.

Comment: your input is the same  as `|\a \b |` tex can not distiguish unless you read verbatim

Comment: @DavidCarlisle but `\verb|\a\b|` somehow prints this correctly. How can I do the same?

Comment: @yegor256 That's because `\verb` reads verbatim, so `\a` is never a control sequence at all

Comment: @JosephWright can you please suggest a complete piece of code that would work "like `\verb`" for my case?

Comment: `\usepackage{shortvrb} \MakeShortVerb|`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer if you post a complete example, I would be happy to accept it as an answer

Comment: `verb` reads verbatim so `\a\b` is four tokens, your macro is getting two tokens `\a` and `\b`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer `\MakeShortVerb|` see my answer to OP's last question;-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle not the last, the one before ;-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to read the argument `v`erbatim:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}

\NewDocumentCommand\foo{v}{\fbox{\color{blue}\ttfamily#1}}

\catcode`\|\active\def|{\foo|}

\begin{document}

bbb |\a\b|!


\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you a LaTeX God of some sort?

Answer (score 1):

The option to use `shortverb` and `\MakeShortVerb|` has already been mentioned in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/665018/2388 so here an alternative with `fancyvrb`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb} 
\DefineShortVerb{\|}
\begin{document}

|\a\b!|

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please, see the updated question. I need `\a\b` to arrive to my own macro. `\texttt` is just an example.

Comment: Check the fancyvrb documentation for options to format the verbatim (or the tcolorbox options mentioned by egreg in the other question).

Comment: I don't want to just format it. I need to catch the entire content and then do many things with it. I would not ask this question if it was just about formatting)

Comment: see the `\SaveVerb` command in fancyvrb.

Answer (score 0):

As `Ulrike Fischer` said :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{shortvrb}

\MakeShortVerb|


\begin{document}

Hello, |\a\b|!

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, see my updated question. I want `\a\b` to arrive to my own macro.

Comment: Why not look into the code of the suggested packages?

Comment: This is my plan B, after I fail here :)

Answer (score 0):

Include `shortvrb` package in your .tex file.

(Copyright 1993--2022 The LaTeX3 Project.)

```
\makeatletter
\def\MakeShortVerb{%
  \@ifstar
    {\def\@shortvrbdef{\verb*}\@MakeShortVerb}%
    {\def\@shortvrbdef{\verb}\@MakeShortVerb}}
\def\@MakeShortVerb#1{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname cc\string#1\endcsname\relax
    \@shortvrbinfo{Made }{#1}\@shortvrbdef
    \add@special{#1}%
    \expandafter
    \xdef\csname cc\string#1\endcsname{\the\catcode`#1}%
    \begingroup
      \catcode`\~\active  \lccode`\~`#1%
      \lowercase{%
      \global\expandafter\let
         \csname ac\string#1\endcsname~%
      \expandafter\gdef\expandafter~\expandafter{\@shortvrbdef~}}%
    \endgroup
    \global\catcode`#1\active
  \else
    \@shortvrbinfo\@empty{#1 already}{\@empty\verb(*)}%
  \fi}
\def\DeleteShortVerb#1{%
  \expandafter\ifx\csname cc\string#1\endcsname\relax
    \@shortvrbinfo\@empty{#1 not}{\@empty\verb(*)}%
  \else
    \@shortvrbinfo{Deleted }{#1 as}{\@empty\verb(*)}%
    \rem@special{#1}%
    \global\catcode`#1\csname cc\string#1\endcsname
    \global \expandafter\let \csname cc\string#1\endcsname \relax
    \ifnum\catcode`#1=\active
      \begingroup
        \catcode`\~\active   \lccode`\~`#1%
        \lowercase{%
          \global\expandafter\let\expandafter~%
          \csname ac\string#1\endcsname}%
      \endgroup \fi \fi}
\def\@shortvrbinfo#1#2#3{%
  \PackageInfo{shortvrb}{%
     #1\expandafter\@gobble\string#2 a short reference
                                          for \expandafter\string#3}}
\def\add@special#1{%
  \rem@special{#1}%
  \expandafter\gdef\expandafter\dospecials\expandafter
    {\dospecials \do #1}%
  \expandafter\gdef\expandafter\@sanitize\expandafter
    {\@sanitize \@makeother #1}}
\def\rem@special#1{%
  \def\do##1{%
    \ifnum`#1=`##1 \else \noexpand\do\noexpand##1\fi}%
  \xdef\dospecials{\dospecials}%
  \begingroup
    \def\@makeother##1{%
      \ifnum`#1=`##1 \else \noexpand\@makeother\noexpand##1\fi}%
    \xdef\@sanitize{\@sanitize}%
  \endgroup}
\makeatother
```